# Where and how do I 'check Drupal permissions' or 'set Drupal permissions'?

Tags: drupal

I find that I am often asked to 'check Drupal permissions' or 'set Drupal permissions' when, for example, I have added a new Component, like Civi Campaigns, Civi Cases, Civi Grants, or, have installed and enabled a new Extension.

But, if I am just getting started with Civi and Drupal, or have not changed my settings in awhile, I may not be sure what that means.

So, where and how do I check Drupal permissions or set Drupal permissions?

Answer (score 2):

In CiviCRM , go to Administer -> Users and Permissions -> Permissions (Access Control) . Then , select Drupal Access Control .

[image: DrupalAccessControl]

You will see a long list of various options, and check boxes to enable permissions for Components, Extensions, etc for various Roles.

[image: PeopleCiviCRM]

Scroll down the list until you see the Component, Extension etc that you have installed and enabled in the list. Then, select the checkbox to add a permission to a Role.

In the screenshot below, I've added permissions for the Administrator role for the ReportPlus extension I just added.

[image: ReportPlusDrupalPermissions]

Save your changes, et voila! You should now see the new permissions for the Administrator role or for whichever role to which you have added new permissions.

Comment: Noting that this isn't actually drupal-specific. That same spot on the same screen will also give links to wordpress permissions and joomla permissions if using those CMS's.

Comment: @Demerit yes, and thanks for noting that.